# Как отправить payload кнопки вк от имени пользователя вк чтобы произошло нажатие? Нужно автоматизировать кое какие нажатия в чате юзерботом вк

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, чат

Я пробовал вот так:

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token,captcha_handler=captcha_handler)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

j = 1500
while True:
    time.sleep(20)
    j = j + 1
    vk.messages.send(user_id=-176640007,message= ".",payload="Тут я пробовал разные варианты но я не понимаю в Json" ,random_id=0)
```

Мне сказали: (Чтобы сделать нажатие на кнопку, надо отсылать payload этой кнопки). Но как найти payload и отослать?[image: Мой вопрос человеку который этим уже занился через python, он больше не в сети уже пол месяца]

[image: Примеры кнопок которые мне нужно автоматически нажимать через юзербота в вк]

Comment: в этой теме я не шарю, но что то мне подсказывает, что у каждой кнопки есть свое значение полезной нагрузки, его и надо указать в моле `payload` метода `send`

Comment: Привет, да, решил эту задачу, payload = '{"command":"mine_i"}' пишется вот в таком виде, одинарные кавычки по бокам

Answer (score 0):

Пишется вот в таком виде, одинарные кавычки по бокам:

```
payload = '{"command":"mine_i"}'
```